# Solving SDE Help Xt^2

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm Trying to solve the sde for $X_t^{2}$

I've started with setting $f(x) = X^{2}$.
Hence f'(x)=2X and f''(x)=2.
$$dY_t= 2X_t(dX_t) + (1/2)2(dX_t)^{2}$$
$$dY_t=2X_t(X_tdB_t)+(X_t)^{2}dt$$
$$dY_t=2X_t^{2}dBt+(X_t)^{2}dt$$
$$Y_t=2\int_0^t(B_s)^{2}dB_s+\int_0^tds$$

Not sure if I've done it right so far and how to go on from here. And if wanted to get the expectation I would typically take the E[itos integral]=0, but im not sure how I could get to that from here.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation seems to be $dX_t=X_t\,dB_t$. It does *not* have a solution $X_t=B_t$. Your Ito formula up to this point is correct, the conclusion should be
$$
dY_t=Y_t\,dt+2Y_t\,dB_t.
$$
As $X_t$ is a geometric Brownian motion, its square is one as well, the SDE for $Y_t$, as well as for any other power, thus is expected to have the general form for a geometric BM.